# Spring Data JPA native-query works with @Query but not with @NamedNativeQuery

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, wildcard, sql-like, nativequery

The following native-query works fine in the PersonRepository using **@Query**:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {
    @Query(value="select * from person where name like %?", nativeQuery=true)
    List<Person> findByPersonName(String name);
}
```

But the following (same native-query) **does not** work with **@NamedNativeQuery**:

```
@Entity
@NamedNativeQuery(name="Person.findByPersonName",
                  query="select * from person where name like %?")
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;
}

public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {    
    List<Person> findByPersonName(String name);
}
```

It throws the following exception when `personRepository.findByPersonName("Bates")` is called:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not prepare statement; SQL [select * from person where name like %?]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
```

Could someone help me understand why am I getting this error with **@NamedNativeQuery**, but not with **@Query**?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the positional index **0** in the `query` of  `@NamedNativeQuery` resolved the issue, as shown in the following code.

```
@Entity
@NamedNativeQuery(name="Person.findByPersonName",
                  query="select * from person where name like %?0")
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;
}

public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {    
    List<Person> findByPersonName(String name);
}
```