Why Spring JPA trying generate query for native query?
I made a native query:
@NamedNativeQuery(
        name = "getting_some_objects_native_query",
        query = "some query",
        resultSetMapping = "some_object_mapper"
)

In the MyJpaRepository<MyObject, UUID>, I made a method for getting objects:
@Query(name = "getting_some_objects_native_query", nativeQuery = true)
List<SomeObject> findSomeObjects(@Param("objectId") UUID objectId);

But I get exception:
Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List MyJpaRepository.findSomeObjects(java.util.UUID); No property 'findSomeObjects' found for type 'MyObject'

It seems that the repository is trying to generate a method, but I indicated that it is native. Why can this happen and how can I fix it?

what happens if you leave off the nativeQuery=true setting in the query annotation? see https://stackoverflow.com/a/31849944/496099

@NamedNativeQuery does not contain a parameter nativeQuery, because it comes from the name of the annotation

If you do not specify it in @Query, the code will not compile

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46171583/jpa-data-repositories-with-sqlresultsetmapping-and-native-queries and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71259143/spring-data-jpa-native-query-works-with-query-but-not-with-namednativequery
